# Add a onclick listener to a view dynamic in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, onclick, listener

I'm beginning in Android.

I'm creating a online app with a chat, and different users, and I can't add a listener to a view that I create with an inflater

I want to make work my OnClick listener in this code :

```
gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery);

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(SavedUsersActivity.this);

for (int i = 0; i < savedUserList.size(); i++){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_profile, gallery, false);

    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.savedName);
    textView.setText(savedUserList.get(i).getName());
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.savedPic);
    String pic = savedUserList.get(i).getImage();
    try{
        //if good set image
        Picasso.get().load(pic).into(imageView);
    }catch (Exception e){
        //if not set default
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_add_image).into(imageView);
    }
    final String hisUid = savedUserList.get(i).getUid();
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SavedUsersActivity.this,ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("hisUid", hisUid);
        }
    });
    gallery.addView(view);
}
```

When I click it doesn't react I think it doesn't work that way but I don't see how to make another. There's a lot of possible users and I want a listenr on every of them to launch the chat with this user. The profiles that the active user saved are in the savedUserList, there can be a lot in it, and there's a list of them on screen to rememeber all the saved users, that can be message with one click on them

Could you please help me to find a way to make this listener to work. I want to launch the ChatActivity by clicking on the view or on the imageview.

Thanks for your help by advance.

Comment: Well.. this is how you set an onclicklistener on a view.. are you sure you are not overriding or removing it somewherr else in your code ?

Comment: No that's the only listener in this activity